# Datastax OpsCenter 5.2.0 fails to backup to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

When I am using Opscenter to even create an Amazon S3 backup job it fails with the following message in the logs and browser. It fails during the create step.. I have tried with all keyspaces and individual keyspaces...DSE version 4.7.1.. Opscenter version 5.2.0. I have just created this cluster.. and creating the backup job for the first time.

Please advise.

2015-07-31 11:41:35+0000 [] ERROR: Problem while calling decorator (LibcloudError):  'This bucket is located in a different region. Please use the correct driver.'>
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

```
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 2119, in DestinationsValidateController

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/backups/Destinations.py", line 488, in validate

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/backups/Destinations.py", line 422, in validate

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/backups/Destinations.py", line 408, in validate_connection

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 207, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/context.py", line 59, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/context.py", line 37, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/backups/Destinations.py", line 400, in run_validate_connection

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/libcloud/storage/drivers/s3.py", line 304, in get_container
        method='HEAD')

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/libcloud/common/base.py", line 736, in request
        response = responseCls(**kwargs)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/libcloud/common/base.py", line 117, in __init__
        raise Exception(self.parse_error())

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/libcloud/storage/drivers/s3.py", line 85, in parse_error
        driver=S3StorageDriver)
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to your *cluter_name*.conf file.  Under the agents heading (I imagine in your case it is blank), and add in the following line:

```
remote_backup_region = <region S3 bucket is in>
```

Appropriate values for the regions are:

```
us-standard 
us-west-1 
us-west-2 
eu-west-1
eu-central-1 
ap-northeast-1 
ap-southeast-1
ap-southeast-2
sa-east-1
```

Once you have saved that setting, restart OpsCenter and try the backup again.

Comment: Also I would like to note that this is a temporary fix.  I can update once a more permanent solution is in place.

Comment: for DSE installed with the linux installer, in my case the file was located at /usr/share/opscenter/conf/clusters/local.conf.

Comment: my bucket is in us-east-1. I used `remote_backup_region = us-standard` in the agents stanza. Validation failed when setting up the remote location in Opscenter. `Location validation error: Call to /local/backups/destination_validate timed out.`

Comment: Hi @PhilB and LHWizard I have scheduled backups of cluster A on bucket A.. I am trying to create a cluster B and directly restore the data from bucket A into it to save time and effort. While I try to restore from backup, I get something similar to LHWizard. Anything I am missing here?

Location validation error: Call to /Development_Cluster/backups/destination_validate timed out.

Comment: @HarshaSharma update or add " [ui] default_api_timeout = 30" to your opscenterd.conf file, then restart OpsCenter.  This will increase the timeout for the api that has timedout with AWS.

Comment: adding the timeout value did not resolve my error btw. see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632621/cant-backup-to-s3-with-opscenter-5-2-1)