# opscenter cluster_name.conf settings

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm working on backup/restore in S3 with Datastax OpsCenter 5.2.1. [This link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/online_help/services/opscManagingBackups_c.html) says

> AWS credentials and bucket names are stored in cluster_name.conf.

Whereas, [this OpsCenter 5.2 doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html) doesn't mention those settings at all.

Separately, the [Opscenter 5.1 doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html) mentions [destinations] stanza which is completely missing from the 5.2 doc.

I'd love to get some clarity here. Thanks.

Comment: currently, I am unable to create/save a scheduled backup to S3. I lost this functionality upon upgrade from 5.1.2 to 5.2.0. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632621/cant-backup-to-s3-with-opscenter-5-2-1). I'd like to get this working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that you are looking at the right docs for your versions. There will be differences between versions of OpsCenter and they will be reflected in the docs accordingly.

In this case, however, both sets of docs are the same.

[5.2](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html#opscConnectionConfig__destinations-active)

[5.1](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html#opscConnectionConfig__destinations-active)

They both read

> [destinations] active¶
>
> Specifies the names of destinations to backup to. They shouldn't have spaces and
>
> should be delimited by comments.

Regarding this note:

> AWS credentials and bucket names are stored in cluster_name.conf.

It is also in both sets of docs and is valid. Please ensure you take security precautions for this file since it has your creds.

I'm afraid this is not related to your [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632621/cant-backup-to-s3-with-opscenter-5-2-1).

Comment: thx. "delimited by comments", tho? is that a typo? Can I manually add AWS credentials? And if so, what are the variable names?

Comment: You should maintain them via the gui